# Access parent within own `ggproto` object

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I want to access `compute_group()` of the parent method within my own `ggproto` object. Here are two different working approaches, but don't know if any is the "correct" way to go:

1. `self$super()$compute_group(...)`
2. `ggproto_parent(<parent>, self)$compute_group(...)`

Any (strong) opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just here to suggest that the correct way to do it is to use your second approach. One reason is that the documentation of `?ggproto` reads:

> To explicitly call a methods in a parent, use ggproto_parent(Parent, self).

A second reason is that ggplot2 source code never uses `self$super()$method()`, from which you could deduce that it is not intended to be used that way.

A third option to consider is to call `OtherClass$compute_group()` directly in your code. This should work because the ggproto classes are designed to be stateless, so this should be safe if you adhere to the statelessness rule. The [ggplot2 book](https://ggplot2-book.org/internals.html#introducing-ggproto) mentions that this pattern in more prevalent than the `ggproto_parent()` method due to its clarity and equivalent safety.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, all three options work! An advantage of using `OtherClass$compute_group()` is that no `self` argument is needed in the new "child" `ggproto` method anymore, a disadvantage might be that it's not that clear, that it is using the parent method. But perhaps the distinction between child and parent method is even no longer important?

Comment: Having re-read the section in the [ggplot2 book](https://ggplot2-book.org/internals.html#ggproto-classes-have-simple-inheritance), I would like to add the relevant paragraphs mentioned by @teunbrand here for clarity: "While we have seen that parent methods can be called using `ggproto_parent()` this pattern is quite rare to find in the `ggplot2` source code, as the pattern shown above is often clearer and just as safe." - referring to calling `OtherClass$method()`.